# Magento 2 - Add link using cms block in PWA venia theme

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio, venia

I am trying to add link using cms block in pwa venia theme. But issue is when I click on link it reloads the whole page, which does not happen when I add link using js file. Does any have any idea how can I solve this isse?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Text and Html components in pagebuilder render data using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, so you get simple  tag.
If you use ButtonItem in Buttons component react-router-dom will be used and navigation will trigger without reloading the PWA. You can also choose button type "link" to make it look like a link.